# Youtube api V3: pagenation video results , trending videos and videos by category

Tags: php, video, youtube-data-api

I need a clarification the following things in youtube api version 3

**1.Get video results with pagination**

i want to get the results with pagination but `nextPageToken` and `prevPageToken` are null from my response.

Here is my code

```
  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setDeveloperKey($DEVELOPER_KEY);
  $youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

    $searchResponse = $youtube->search->listSearch('id,snippet', array(
            'type' => 'video',
            'q' => $_GET['q'],
            /*'location' =>  $_GET['location'],
            'locationRadius' =>  $_GET['locationRadius'],*/
            'maxResults' => 50,
            'order' => 'viewCount'
        ));
```

**2.Getting Most popular videos**

How to get the most popular videos from the api i"ve tried with parameter
  `'chart' => 'mostPopular'` but it will through error `unknown parameter chart`

**3.Get video by category**

How can i get list of videos by category eg:  get the list of videos under `music` category

Comment: you want to get this by using youtube example php script, or by url which responds to api.

Answer (score 0):

get most popular videos by using listVideos not listSearch:

```
$trendingComedy = $youtube->videos->listVideos('snippet', array(
  'chart' => 'mostPopular',
  'maxResults' => 50,
  'regionCode' => 'GB',
  'videoCategoryId' => '23'
));
```